# PHP How to change date format from variable

Tags: php

im currently pulling data from my database along with a date via variable. 
The code im using is this

`echo "".$row["firstname"]." ".$row["lastname"]." thinks that it will happen on ".$row["date"]."";`

the results are being displayed as :
*bobby anderson thinks that it will happen on **2011-09-15***

but id like the date to be displayed as **Monday 1st August 2011**

Comment: Please post the column type for date and the type of database you are using

Answer (score 6):

```
date('l jS F Y',strtotime($row['date']))
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function, along with [strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php).

Answer (score 1):

You can either use date along with strtotime, or you can use the date_create_from_format method (date_create_from_format example):

```
echo DateTime::createFromFormat( "Y-n-j", $row['date'])
     ->format( 'l jS F Y' );
```

(an now strtotime)

```
echo date('l jS F Y',strtotime($row['date']));
```

Comment: +1 for using DateTime. *PRO TIP* DateTime is a PHP 5 >= 5.3.0 function.  It is easy to use, but if you are using an earlier version you'll need to go with the second recipe!

Comment: Yea, all of my stuff is on PHP 5.3. I don't normally think about that limitation.

Comment: Some enterprise installs of linux don't use 5.3 yet.  Just something to keep in mind.